# How to stop VS Code terminal from printing file path upon every run?

Tags: windows-7, terminal, python, visual-studio-code

I've just started learning Python and I'm fairly new to VS code. Fairly new as in, installed it about an hour ago. I was wondering if I can stop the terminal from printing this filepath (highlighted in the picture) every time I run my file? It's just annoying.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tarli.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is the VS Code's console, and your machine's DOS prompt, which is usually the current path. To change it you can use the "prompt" command in that same window, like this:

```
prompt $$
```

would change the prompt to a UNIX-like `$`.
or

```
prompt $g
```

for the unadorned DOS-like `>`

If that works, there should be a setting for shell initialization in VS code, where you can add that command, or edit your system-wide `autoexec.bat` file.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and direct response. It worked without any need to add prompt or editing autoexec.bat.